# Integrating login with facebook in swift using Django as backend

Tags: python, ios, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate login with Facebook in my iOS app which I did successfully. After that I want to authenticate the user and save it in my backend which is Django.

What I have done is that I have a web-app with:

- Django Rest Framework
- django-rest-framework-social-oauth2
- Python social auth

I have studied the OAuth2 flow and also tried the example given at:

> https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

I created an application in my backend with the help of Django OAuth toolkit and with the given client id and client secret I was successfully able to send a POST request using curl with the access token provided by Facebook. It returns me a dictionary like this ,

> {"access_token":"An access token over here","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":36000,"refresh_token":"Refresh token over here","scope":"read write"}

I have a lot of confusions so how do I go about getting the user from my front-end and then associating and making a user in my back-end and later on checking if all the actions are done by that user (like referencing the user).

What I have understood is that in my front-end which is my swift-app I should be making my user login with Facebook. Facebook authenticates the user and then returns an access token. I should be sending that access token to my API and get an access token from there for it? Do I have to write some custom views for it? Any help would be appreciated

NOTE: I have gone through all the android, iOS to Django questions, tutorials and articles

**UPDATE-1:**

Through my iOS app I am able to login the user with Facebook. I pass the Facebook token to /authorize/convert-token/ url and get back an access_token. The documentation says that you should be using this access_token on all your requests. As a newbie how should I go about it? Save the access_token in my iOS app and how do I constantly make requests with this token?

Comment: Hey! Did you figure it out?

Comment: Hi @ShreeRangaRaju! Yes, if you read the Update-1 above that is how you would go about it and once you have the access token from the backend, you will be using that for all further requests.

Answer (score 0):

First install the Facebook SDK for iOS. This will give you a LoginButton which you can drop into your app:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login

Once you get Facebook's auth token, you do a token conversion on your own server to get the access_token (as you mentioned above, with /authorize/convert-token/). This is the token which you can include in the header of your HTTP requests to your Django server (the following example is using Alamofire):

```
headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token]
Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
```

Comment: I get the access token and was able to pass it using Alamofire. I get back an access_token. How should I go about using  this token on all my requests?

Comment: Once you have converted your token, you use the line above.It's just that I've called access_token authToken.